# Is there a way to label points in 3D Desmos?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, desmos

So I am working on making a cube in Desmos 3D with labeled vertices.

If anyone would like the link to the Desmos 3D graph, [here it is](https://www.desmos.com/3d/23655e0b32).

The only problem is, I am unable to label the vertices for some weird reason, when I put down a point, such as at $(1,1,1)$, there is no (Label) button that pops up so I can label the point as say `(1,1,1)`, as seen in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7d6R.png) screenshot:

[image]

My question is, is there some sort of workaround to applying labels to points in Desmos 3D, or is there no way of getting around this limitation?

I have tried clicking and long-holding the color icon on the point to attempt to get around not being able to label the point, as that does work in Desmos 2D (or just Desmos), but it doesn't appear to work.

While scrolling through Google searching for workarounds, I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/desmos/comments/174wtyg/point_labels_in_desmos_3d/) Reddit post in /r/desmos from a user who was trying to redo the coordinate system in Desmos 3D and wanted to know if they could label points, but nobody has commented on that post.

Comment: As a workaround use GeoGebra instead of Desmos.

Comment: I emailed support about it. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @Paul Oh that's cool! Despite GeoGebra having you type out stuff more like you would in Mathematica (i.e. having to type `Integral(f(x,y),x)` instead of just being able to do `int` in Desmos), it does seem to have what I need. Thank you!

Comment: The [tag:desmos] tag is a pretty low-traffic tag.  I don't think that a second Desmos related tag is necessary at this time.

Comment: I got a response from the support team and they said there is currently no way to label points in 3D. They've passed the feature request along to the development team so hopefully they add it at some point.